# Titlesec and xcolor not playing nicely?

Tags: sectioning, color, titlesec, capitalization

I am trying to use the `titlesec` and `xcolor` packages together (well, actually, the `tufte-book` class is, but that's another story.)

Here is a minimal LaTeX file that illustrates my problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcase}
\titleformat{\part}[block]{}{\thepart}{1em}{\textcolor{darkgray}\MakeTextUppercase}
\begin{document}
\part{A Tale of Two Cities}
\end{document}
```

The 5th argument of `\titleformat` is supposed to add the section heading as an argument to the last command, so it should end up with `\MakeTextUppercase{A Tale of Two Cities}`. But running LaTeX on this file produces the following output:

> ! Argument of \MakeTextUppercase has an extra }.
>   Runaway argument?
>   ! Paragraph ended before \MakeTextUppercase was complete.

However, if I remove `\textcolor{darkgray}` then everything works as expected. Also, if I insert `\\` between `\textcolor{darkgray}` and `\MakeTextUppercase`, then everything also works as expected. But not if I put `\\` before `\textcolor{darkgray}`.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\textcolor` requires two arguments and with your code the first is `darkgray` and the second is `\MakeTextUppercase`, which is wrong.

However, the title is typeset in a group, so

```
\titleformat{\part}[block]{}{\thepart}{1em}{\color{darkgray}\MakeTextUppercase}
```

will do (and probably you want to apply the coloring also to `\thepart`).

Comment: Excellent. My fault for assuming I knew what `\textcolor` does...